# SQL Cartesian type join

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables (simplified for this example) which I want to join in a particular way.

- Table 1 (ae) has subject number, ae term
- Table 2 (mh) has subject number, mh term

heres the construct to help

```
INSERT INTO ae VALUES ('0001-0012','DRY EYE (12 OCT 2017)');
INSERT INTO ae VALUES  ('0001-0012', 'DEPRESSION (7 OCT 2017)');
INSERT INTO ae VALUES ('0001-0013','SKIN ATROPHY, LEFT UPPER ARM (4 OCT 2017 )');


INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0012', 'DIABETES MELLITUS (UN JUL 2007)');
INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0012', 'GASTRO-ESOPHAGEAL REFLUX INTERMITENT GR1 (18 AUG 2017)');
INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0012', 'ESOPHAGITIS GR 1 (18 AUG 2017)');
INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0012', 'DIARRHEA INITERMITTENT GR2 (5 JUL 2017 )');
INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0012', 'FATIGUE INTERMITTENT GR1 (18 AUG 2017)');
INSERT INTO mh VALUES ('0001-0013', 'VOMITING, INTERMITTENT GR1 (6 JUL 2017 )');
```

I want my output to look like this:
[image: output]

Any help out there? As you can see its a gnarly join I need!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms?  What have you tried so far????  Put some effort!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you expect to be the output?

Comment: What is the logic? What row of ae match with mh, beside  the subject number? Because if date is relevant here that should be in a separated field.

Comment: Date is not relevant as its part of the text string in the ae term and mh term fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and `full join`:

```
select coalesce(ae.col1, mh.col1) as col1, ae.col2, mh.col2
from (select ae.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as seqnum
      from ae
     ) ae full join
     (select mh.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as seqnum
      from mh
     ) mh
     on mh.col1 = ae.col1 and mh.seqnum = ae.seqnum
order by coalesce(ae.col1, mh.col1), seqnum;
```

Comment: if you mean `col1 = subject number` then you can have random pairing here. I guess OP should separated date from term and create one additional field.

Answer (score 0):

heres my updated code so far it now gives me the correct order EDIT Just added the DESC at the end of the code to give me the result

```
select coalesce(ae.subject, mh.subject) as subject, ae.aeterms, mh.mhterms
from (select ae.*, row_number() over (partition by subject order by subject) 
as seqnum
from ae) ae full join
(select mh.*, row_number() over (partition by subject order by subject) as 
seqnum from mh) mh
on mh.subject = ae.subject and mh.seqnum = ae.seqnum
order by coalesce(ae.subject, mh.subject), ae.seqnum Desc;
```