# FULL OUTER JOIN type join needed in SAS EG 5.1 using PROC SQL

Tags: sql, join, sas

Following a successful answer for my question [SQL Cartesian type join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911535/sql-cartesian-type-join/48912061#48912061)

I need to use this method in SAS to work on some tables. The SQL code is here and I have tried it out in SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51b94/1

```
SELECT coalesce(ae.subject, mh.subject) AS subject
    ,ae.aeterms
    ,mh.mhterms
FROM (
    SELECT ae.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY subject
            ) AS seqnum
    FROM ae
    ) ae
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT mh.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY subject
            ) AS seqnum
    FROM mh
    ) mh ON mh.subject = ae.subject
    AND mh.seqnum = ae.seqnum
ORDER BY coalesce(ae.subject, mh.subject)
    ,ae.seqnum DESC;
```

However I know that row_number() over is not available is SAS.

Comment: In SAS, this is probably more easily done in a data step.  However, my SAS programming is a little rusty, so perhaps someone else will write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL was designed to ignore row order, which is why they had to add the windowing functions that you are trying to use.

If you want to add a sequence number to your data then use a data step.

```
data ae_seq ;
  set ae;
  by subject ;
  if first.subject then seqnum=0;
  seqnum+1;
run;
data mh_seq ;
  set mh;
  by subject ;
  if first.subject then seqnum=0;
  seqnum+1;
run;
```

But it looks you are really just trying to force SQL to mimic a data step MERGE.  When you do a many to many merge in SAS it matches the first row from one table to the first row from the other, etc.  When one table contributes fewer rows then the values from the last row are carried forward onto the rest of the rows in that by group.  To prevent SAS from carrying forward the values from the last row contributed by the shorter dataset you can use CALL MISSING() to clear them out.

```
data want ;
  merge ae mh ;
  by subject ;
  output ;
  call missing(of _all_);
run;
```